# Why does the eclipse 2023-06 fail to copy symlinked maven resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, symlink

Eclipse 2023-06 includes the new M2E 2.3.0, which in turn includes maven 3.9 (up from 3.8). By default the new maven release uses the maven-resources v3.3.0 plugin. When trying to build existing projects with symlinked files, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources {execution: default-resources} (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources {execution: default-resources}
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.lambda$0(MavenExecutionContext.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.lambda$1(MavenBuilderImpl.java:139)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: copying /home/test.git/testProject/src/main/resources/I18NConstants_da.properties to /home/test.git/testProject/target/classes/I18NConstants_da.properties failed with NoSuchFileException: /home/test.git/testProject/target/classes/I18NConstants_da.properties
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeMojo(MavenExecutionContext.java:338)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: copying /home/test.git/testProject/src/main/resources/I18NConstants_da.properties to /home/test.git/testProject/target/classes/I18NConstants_da.properties failed with NoSuchFileException: /home/test.git/testProject/target/classes/I18NConstants_da.properties
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:356)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/test.git/testProject/target/classes/I18NConstants_da.properties
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setMode(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setPermissions(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:299)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2167)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.FilteringUtils.copyFilePermissions(FilteringUtils.java:477)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.FilteringUtils.copyFile(FilteringUtils.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:110)
    ... 36 more
```

Is this new bug fixed with a later version? How can I work around these issues for now?

Comment: Please share the whole pom file...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the following bug [MSHARED-1112](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-1112), which was introduced with maven-resources-plugin 3.2.0 and fixed in 3.3.1.

There's also another bug that you might hit: [MRESOURCES-265](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-265), which causes resource files with e.g. ISO-8859-1 encoding to break the maven resource filtering.

I mitigated the issues, by downgrading to version 3.0.1, like this:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
```